# How to save data without creating new object on database mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

i try to save data using bot command, but everytime i submit the data it will make new object, i want to make it only 1 object but everytime the same user submit data, it will automtically got changes/update, not create new object.

This is how i save the data

```
const subregis = "!reg ign:";
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content.includes(subregis)){ 
      const user = new User({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        userID: msg.author.id,
        nickname: msg.content.substring(msg.content.indexOf(":") + 1) // so basically anything after the : will be the username
      });
      user.save().then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
      msg.reply("Data has been submitted successfully") 
  }
});
```

This is my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const profileSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userID: String,
    nickname: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", profileSchema);
```

everytime i do command `!reg ign` it will add new object, not save/update the exiting user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is check if there is data related to that user before creating a collection.

```js
Schema.findOne({ userID: msg.author.id }, async (err, data) =>{
   if (data) {
       return msg.reply({content: `you already have a nickname, it's ${data.nicknamd}})
   }
   if (!data) {
       // Create the Schema
   }
})
```

If you want to update the nickname use

```js
const newdata = Schema.findOneandUpdate({}) ...
//then follow what lpizzini said above
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an existing `User` you should use the `findOneAndUpdate` function:

```
const subregis = '!reg ign:';
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  try {
    if (msg.content.includes(subregis)) {
      const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { userID: msg.author.id },
        {
          nickname: msg.content.substring(msg.content.indexOf(':') + 1), // so basically anything after the : will be the username
        },
        {
          new: true, // Return an updated instance of the User
        }
      );
      console.log(updatedUser);
      msg.reply('Data has been submitted successfully');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```